# How to search for product by name or sku programatically?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, collection, search

Need search by name "or" sku

```
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource') -> getConnection('core_read');

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('like' => '%'.$search.'%'))
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => '%'.$search.'%'))
                    ->load();
```

This code works but only by name

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301231/addattributetofilter-and-or-condition-in-magentos-collection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the OR operator you need to use several arrays.

In your case:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToFilter(
                        array(
                            array('attribute' => 'sku', 'like' => '%'.$search.'%'),
                            array('attribute' => 'name', 'like' => '%'.$search.'%')
                        )
                    )
                    ->load();
```

To limit the results to 10 products you can add `->setPageSize(10)->setCurPage(1)` just before the `load()`

Comment: Yes yes, thank you, i sorted it out in the meantime :)

Comment: If you know, just advise me please how to limit the number of products to for example 10 ?

Comment: @RobertA. see my edited answer

Comment: It will return all child. so Any suggestion return to parent instead?